# Creating static variable for current user Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

After authenticating into the app, I have multiple view controllers where I need to display the current user's profile picture, bio, and some other information.

The problem I'm trying to avoid is every single time the user goes into their settings page, I don't want to have to go fetch their bio / other info.

Instead of sending off a request to fetch that information on each view controller, it seems like a better idea to just create a static instance of the "currentUser" on my User class while I'm authenticating, grab the user's info, set the info,  and THEN segue into the app and use that variable throughout my app for my calls and for setting labels.

Is there any reason NOT to do this? People seem to advice to not use static variables, but in this case it seems like a cleaner solution than passing around my currentUser every time I segue.

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to use singletons sparingly, because they are an irregularity in your flow of data.

That said, a `currentUser` for your `User` class seems to fit this criteria *exactly*.

If your data is setup correctly, the common concerns of using singletons (testing etc) are very easy to deal with, even if your testing logic within individual `UIViewControllers`, (even though I believe that anything testable shouldn't be in a VC!). To do this, you should set up your `User` class for dependency injection/mocking, so you can easily test things when you get around to it.

Here's my idea of a well-set up `User` singleton, that lends itself to testing later:

```
class YourUser {

    var email: String?
    let id: String

    static var currentUser: YourUser?

}
```

I like having an `init` with `Auth` that just sets the current user to the auth data,

```
    /// Inits with a Firebase user, and sets the current user to fir user
    ///
    /// - Parameter firUser: Firebase user
    init(withAuthUser authUser: AuthUser) {

        id = authUser.uid
        email = authUser.email

        YourUser.currentUser = self
}
```

And `AuthUser` is just an abstraction of the data I want from `Auth` (for testing purposes).

```
protocol AuthUser: class {
    var email: String? { get }
    var uid: String { get }
}

extension User: AuthUser { }
```

Comment: This seems to be what the OP already has (more or less). He's asking about whether to use a static variable or to pass a reference each time.

Comment: Thanks for point that out, I didn't quite read the question correctly. I added more information to tailor my answer better.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Auth.auth().currentUser` to check for the current user, you're not fetching anything.  It will return the current User, or nil if they're not logged in.  See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big reasons to avoid static variables is testing. If you aren't already writing tests, I highly recommend getting into the habit - you'll be amazed at how less frequently things break. But anyways, suppose you want to test the logic of your view controller. If that controller has a bunch of references to that static variable, well, it's stuck that way. You may be able to hack in some special case inside the static variable to return something different when you're running tests, but it'll be a mess, if you can even get it working at all. However, if your view controller takes some `User` object on init (or as a var), where you can pass the current user, you can write your tests by passing in some dummy user with fake data, and ensure everything works.

So that's one of the main reasons I've moved away from using static variables. Another one is simultaneous access. The more objects you have that reference the same thing, the greater chance that you try accessing something from one spot as it's being mutated in another. Or you mutate something rapidly in a couple of different areas and need to write some additional code to handle if the object was mutated elsewhere.

Now, if these two reasons aren't compelling and you want to use a static variable, I would highly recommend you pass around some lightweight struct that has info on the user - things like their bio as you mention. Instead of just the Firebase Auth User. There's definitely no reason you need to perform this fetch every time you enter a new controller.